# What does ''population'' mean in regards to the excited and ground states of an atom?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a problem I'm working on. It seems simple enough, but there is a term I'm not familiar with. It asks for the ''relative populations of the first excited and the ground states for helium gas in thermal equilibrium at 10,000K.'' We are learning about the partition function in my statistical physics class.

Comment: If $P_0$ is the population of the ground state and $P_1$ is the population of the first excited state it's asking for the ratio $P_1/P_0$.

Comment: @JohnRennie right but what is the definition of a  population?

Comment: The population is just the number of helium atoms in the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume each atom can be in only two states, n = 1 and n = 2, where its energy is respectively E1 and E2.

In a gas, you have many atoms. At any given time, some of them are in state n = 1 and the rest are in state n = 2. The number of atoms in a state n is the "population of the state n ".